# SSH worked fine but scp fails

Tags: ssh, ant, passwords, scp, openssh

I am able to SSH and SCP from my local to the server but when I try to ant deploy; it does not work for me but works for my colleague. I get permission denied error, I am unable to understand if I am able to SSH from my local and also SCP a file from my local to the server, what am I missing.

I am running the following command through my script :

```
<sshexec host="${scp.hostname}"
                 username="${scp.user}"
         keyfile="${scp.keyfile}"
                 trust="true"
                 command="mkdir -p ${projects.home}/${project.name}/${target.dir}" />
```

This is the error I see :

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@481c22e0
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:664)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:561)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:407)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:367)
```

I checked the path for getting the key information is `.ssh/id_rsa`

But my OPENSSH Private key does not start with B@481c22e0 as listed in the error message.

Thanks,

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe in more detail what you're doing and how it's failing. What command are you running? What exact errors do you get? Include the relevant parts of your ant configuration and your ssh configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this command fixed the issue for me.

```
ssh-keygen -p -m pem -f id_rsa
```